# connection between VBox and the host

Tags: lamp, virtualbox, turnkeylinux.org

How can i connect LAMP turnkeylinux in virtualBox with the host, i laready tryed the tutorial in the documentation but don't work, i used the bridge port but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and most secure would be to use host-only networking. Just do a Google search and find e.g. this:

http://ptony82.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/the-fastest-way-to-create-host-only-network-with-virtualbox/